# ALL UIButton's delay executing block

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

My project has `UIButtons` which are taking up to 1 second to execute the block of code.

I have buttons in other projects working fine, but for some odd reason, this project has an annoying delay.

The buttons are dailer numbers, so they need to be pressed quickly:
 Heres an example of one:

```
- (IBAction)phonePressed:(id)sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *backspaceGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backspace)];
    UIButton *one = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(menuShadowLayer2.frame.origin.x+10, menuShadowLayer2.frame.origin.y+10, 80, 80)];
    one.layer.cornerRadius = 40;
    one.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    one.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    [one setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:0.3]];
    [one setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [one.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [one setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [one.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Light" size:50]];
    [container addSubview:one];
    [one addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
...

- (void)dailed1 {
    numberDailed.text = [numberDailed.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
    NSLog(@"1");
}
```

Here is another button using UIControlEventTouchUpInside, which is just as slow if not slower.

```
UIButton *cancel = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(numberDailed.frame.origin.x, numberDailed.frame.origin.y+200, numberDailed.frame.size.width+40, 110)];
    cancel.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    [cancel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cancel.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [container addSubview:cancel];
    [cancel addTarget:self
             action:@selector(clearNumber:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
...

-(IBAction)clearNumber:(id)sender{
    [numberDailed setText:@""];
}
```

I have used a `UITapGestureRecognizer` as using the Button `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` or `TouchDown` was even slower.

When pressing this button (`one`), I have to wait around half a second to a second before tapping again. This obviously creates frustration when your entering a number and half of the numbers haven't been added to the string.

I have set the `UIScrollView` to `delaysContentTouches = NO;`
The button highlights immediately. It simply wont execute the code straight away. 
I have used button `one` as an example, but this applies to ALL `UIButtons` in my project.
Thoughts?

Comment: Why are you using a tap gesture on a `UIButton`? `UIButton` has built in support for handling taps.

Comment: Why does a button have tap gesture ?You should not add any tap gesture to button as it already has one. You should use UIControlEventTouchUpInside and why it is slower ? Please add more details.

Comment: @rmaddy I use UIControlEventTouchUpInside usually, but as mentioned in the post, its even slower than my tap gesture.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or the simulator using a magic pad?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I wish I knew! I have tried looking into every thing to show why its slow. Its in a UIView, which is in a UIScrollView. there isn't much on the view so I don't see why its slow.

Comment: @rmaddy im testing on a real device, iPhone 6s Plus, iOS10

Comment: Why the buttons are in a scroll view any reason?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri the The UIScrollView is just part of the interface, to allow user to slide between two views easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the `MapBox API`(Not Recommended) in my project, removing this sped everything up. All code was fine, have gone back to performing selector and removed the gestures.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are using the gesture,

```
[one addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
```

instead, you should use the button action

```
[one addTarget:self action: @selector(dailed1:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things. Firstly, create your button like so:

```
UIButton *numberButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
numberButton.frame = CGRectMake(...);
```

Secondly, as others have pointed out, you do not need any gestures, but should attach an action/target to the button:

```
[numberButton addTarget:self action:@selector(numberDialled:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Thirdly, create your IBAction:

```
- (IBAction) numberDialled:(id)sender
```